# Nginx. Restricting https requests to one domain

Tags: nginx

I'm running an api behind Nginx. 
A Certbot SSL certificate was set up on the company's domain through Nginx.

I can make use of the api through, let's say `https://www.my-domain.com` and there is an application at `https://www.another-app.com` that consumes the first domain only through `https`.

Right now everyone can access the data on `https://www.my-domain.com` but I need the nginx server to only be accessible from **all subdomains** of `https://www.another-app.com`

Here is my nginx default config file

```
server{

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name my-domain.com www.my-domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000; 
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-domain.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.my-domain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = my-domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 


    if ($host = www.my-domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 

server_name my-domain.com www.my-domain.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; 
}
```

Comment: As for your title...restrict access to what, the API? What is the path of the API? Need you to be more specific.

Comment: Sure! I need to restrict the access to make https requests to nginx to just one domain.

Comment: I see. Well you are talking about two different domain names and an API. The API seems irrelevant and makes your question confusing. If the API is relevant, explain how. Please narrow the question to the issue at hand.

Comment: Right. I need the nginx server hosted on `https://www.my-domain.com` to be accesible only from all subdomains of `https://www.another-app.com`

Comment: For starters, have you tried changing `server_name my-domain.com www.my-domain.com;` to `server_name another-app.com www.another-app.com;`?

Answer (score 0):

People are going to vote to close this on the basis you've not provided enough information/requires more focus.

Your problem definition - that you want to restrict access based on the domain - is unclear. The term "domain" applies to different things in different contexts. Assuming that you are referring to a DNS domain - then you need to rethink the the problm. While it is possible to use PTR records to resolve which DNS domain a host belongs to in practice most people don't maintain PTR records for technical reasons and the limited benefits they bring. Even if the data is there, it will be very slow to use this for authentication on each request. Ultimately this boils to authorizing access based on the claimed identity of the host - which has very little security value.

OTOH if all the machines are in the same subnet, your company controls the subnet and there are no hosts on the subnet to be excluded, in that context using the IP address for authentication may have some value - nginx happily handles this out of the box using CIDR based notation.

For a distributed set of hosts (i.e. not all in the same subnet) you will need to use some sort of token based authentication. The common ones are shared secrets (passwords) and client certificates.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I have a Nginx server running on `https://www.my-domain.com` and it is accesible for everyone. I need the Nginx server to only accept connections from `https://www.another-app.com`. Hope that is more useful...